# Как сделать чтоб после обратного отчета таймера в tkinter открывалось 100 cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я недавно начал изучать python и решил в ознакомительных целях написать на нем вирус. Нашел в интернете код для таймера, немного его доработал, чтоб у вируса пропал крестик и скрыть/раскрыть, чтоб его нельзя было менять в размерах и чтоб он всегда был поверх других окон, но я не знаю как в коде сделать так, чтобы после окончания таймера открывалось 100 cmd,еще было бы неплохо чтоб windows после этого уходил в перезагрузку, если это вообще можно сделать в python.

Пишу я в IDEA на версии 3.9.

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt


class CountdownLabel(tk.Label):
""" A Label in the format of HH:MM:SS, that displays counting down from given 
seconds.
"""

def __init__(self, master, seconds_left):
    super().__init__(master)
    self._seconds_left = seconds_left
    self._timer_on = False
    self._countdown()                   # Start counting down immediately

def _start_countdown(self):
    self._stop_countdown()
    self._countdown()

def _stop_countdown(self):
    if self._timer_on:
        self.after_cancel(self._timer_on)
        self._timer_on = False

def _countdown(self):
    self['text'] = self._get_timedelta_from_seconds(self._seconds_left)
    if self._seconds_left:
        self._seconds_left -= 1
        self._timer_on = self.after(1000, self._countdown)

@staticmethod
def _get_timedelta_from_seconds(seconds):
    return dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

countdown = CountdownLabel(root, 300)
countdown.pack()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("300x420+500+200")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ах тыж пакостник

Comment: а что такого?ето исключительно в целях понять как работают подобные программы чтоб можно было от них защититься

Comment: Ничего против не имею)  Просто пошутил

Comment: Неужели редактор перестал подчеркивать ошибки красным?

Comment: не перестал он по прежнему подчеркивает ошибки

Comment: @Sheud_z я про грамматические ошибки в тексте Вашего вопроса... Их сложно исправить? Это же люди читают.

Comment: а я не из росси чтоб свободно говорить на етом языке

Comment: @Sheud_z говорить и не надо. Писать Вам помогает здешний редактор или этот сервис https://text.ru/spelling

Comment: @Konstantin_SH ошибки подчеркивает не здешний редактор, а браузер. Если в браузере не установлен словарь русского языка, то орфографические ошибки подчеркиваться не будут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот код открывает `cmd`:

```
import os
os.startfile(r'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe')
```

Чтобы открыть 100 `cmd`, сделайте цикл и в нём открывайте `cmd`

Comment: код для открытия cmd то я имею но поскольку я лиш доработал код а не создавал его я не совсем понимаю куда вписать данную команду чтоб открывались cmd

Comment: Ааааа, вот оно что. Я думал вы взяли и разобрались в этом коде)

Comment: Можно с помощью `treading` запустить код с открытием `cmd` в отдельном потоке. https://webdevblog.ru/vvedenie-v-potoki-v-python/ Ну и прописать это после `root.mainloop()`

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: Да не за что) Если ответ поможет, то отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ галочкой)